# Guardar en tabla temporal el resultado de un EXEC(@variable)

Tags: sql, sql-server, reportviewer

tengo una consulta que es totalmente dinamica, utilice PIVOT, lo que hace la consulta es dependiendo el rango de fecha que se coloque
arroja las columnas de los meses que esten dentro de las fechas dichas, si unicamente elijo 2 meses, las columnas de mes me apareceran 2 meses

lo que quiero es hacer un reporte en ReportBuilder pero no se como hacer esto, queria meterlo en una tabla temporal este resultado pero
no se como hacerlo

comparto el query

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#calendar') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #calendar;

   IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Columnas') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #Columnas;


DECLARE @FechaInicio DATE ='20210101'
DECLARE @FechaFin DATE ='20221231'
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @columnas VARCHAR(MAX)


SET @FechaFin = CONVERT(DATE,IIF(@FechaFin>GETDATE(), GETDATE(),@FechaFin));


WITH Calendario AS (
SELECT  DISTINCT CONCAT(RIGHT(CONCAT('00',MONTH(c.CalendarDate)),2),'-',YEAR(c.CalendarDate)) Fecha, EOMONTH(c.CalendarDate) FinMes

FROM dbo.Calendar c
WHERE c.CalendarDate BETWEEN @FechaInicio AND @FechaFin
)
SELECT c.numerocontrato,
c.Description AS [Fideicomiso],
--DATENAME(MONTH,ca.FinMes) Mes,
MONTH(ca.FinMes)Mesnum,
YEAR(ca.FinMes) Año, 
dbo.f_GetBalance(c.numerocontrato,ca.FinMes, 'All') Saldo
INTO #calendar
FROM contrato c



, Calendario ca
WHERE c.numerocontrato IN ('349743113',
'54794113497',

)


SELECT DISTINCT C.Mesnum 
INTO #Columnas
FROM #calendar c
ORDER BY c.Mesnum

select @columnas = ISNULL(@columnas +'],[','') + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,c.Mesnum)
FROM #Columnas C

SET @columnas = '['+@columnas+']'


set @query='Select * from
(
SELECT numerocontrato, Fid, Mesnum, año, Saldo
FROM #calendar
)t
PIVOT
(
--sumamos el valor a mostrar
sum(Saldo)
--ponemos el nombre de la variable
--de columnas
FOR Mesnum IN ('+@columnas+')
) AS PivotTable;
'

EXECUTE (@query)



   IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#calendar') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #calendar;

   
   IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Columnas') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #Columnas;
```

Answer (score 1):

Para insertar en una tabla (sea esta temporal o variable tipo tabla) las filas resultantes de la ejecución de una sentencia `EXECUTE` la sintaxis es

```
INSERT INTO @NombreTabla (Columna1, Columna2, ..., ColumbaN)
EXECUTE Procedimiento ó CadenaSqlDinamica
```

Los unicos requisitos son:

- Enunciar las columnas en las que se insertaran los datos
- Estar seguro de que el procedimiento almacenady y/o el sql dinamico devuelve solo filas de la misma estructura de datos. O sea un solo conjunto de datos o si vienen varios los mismos deben tener la misma cabtidad y tipos de columnas

Por ejemplo:

```
create table #Test (
    uno int,
    dos varchar(max)
)

-- Inserta en tabla #Test ...
insert into #Test(uno, dos)
-- Los valores 1 y 'dos' resultantes de ejecutar el dinámico
execute N'select 1, ''dos'''
```

Ahora, para el caso mas particular de la pregunta donde la estructura de la tabla temporal # en la que se deben insertar en la que se insertaran los datos no se conoce sino en tiempo de ejecución la tabla# se tendría que crear y modificar con sql dinámico para agregar las columnas requeridas.

Plantearé aquí una demostración más genérica:

**I. Creacion de tablas para la demostracion**

```
-- Creacion de tabla para la demostracion
create table datos (
     grupo varchar(4)
    ,valor int
);
-- Poblando los datos para la demostracuion
insert into datos (grupo,valor)
values ('1011',10)
      ,('1011',20)
      ,('1012',30)
      ,('1012',40)
      ,('2001',50)
;

-- Consulta que se desea pivotear
select grupo,sum(valor)
  from datos
 group by grupo
```

**II. Script con creación de tabla temporal dinámica e inserción de datos pivoteados**

El script a continuación:

- Calcula la lista de columnas que se necesitan en la tabla temporal en la que se insertarán los datos del pivote y la lista de columnas con tipo para agregarlas a la tabla temporal
- Crea una tabla temporal #tmp_tpivot y la altera para agregarle las columnas requeridas para almacenar los datos del pivote
- Calcula en `@PivotDinamico` el texto de la sentencia sql que obtiene los datos pivoteados y los inserta en la tabla temporal

```
BEGIN

    declare
        @CreaTempo nvarchar(max)
       ,@ColumnasTempo nvarchar(max)

    /** Determina cuales son las columnas requeridas por cada grupo en la tabla temporal y en el pivote **/
    set @CreaTempo = ''
    set @ColumnasTempo= ''
    ;with
     -- Consulta agrupada
     c1 as (select grupo,sum(valor) as suma
              from datos
            group by grupo)
    --Concatena en la variable @CreaTempo la declaracion de columnas tipo INT
    --Concatena en la variable @ColumnasTempo el conjunto de columnas sin tipo
    select @CreaTempo=@CreaTempo+iif(@CreaTempo<>'',',','')+'['+grupo+'] int'
          ,@ColumnasTempo=@ColumnasTempo+iif(@ColumnasTempo<>'',',','')+'['+grupo+']'
      from c1

    --Crea una tabla temporal con columna identidad
    create table #tmp_tpivot (rowid int identity); 
    --Calcula sql dinamico que agrega las columnas a pivotear a la tabla #tmp_tpivot
    set @CreaTempo = 'alter table #tmp_tpivot add '+@CreaTempo+';' --
    --Ejecuta el dinamico para agregar las columnas #tmp_tpivot
    exec sp_executesql @CreaTempo;


    declare @PivotDinamico nvarchar(max)
    -- Se calcula la sentencia INSERT SELECT para insertar en la tabla temporal los datos del pivote
    set @PivotDinamico =
        N'INSERT INTO #tmp_tpivot('+@ColumnasTempo+')'
      + N'SELECT '+@ColumnasTempo+' FROM (SELECT grupo,valor FROM datos) AS SourceTable PIVOT (sum(valor) FOR grupo IN ('+@ColumnasTempo+')) AS PivotTable'
    --Ejecuta el dinamico que inserta en #tmp_tpivot los datos del pivote
    exec sp_executesql @PivotDinamico;

    --Mostrando resultados
    select *
      from #tmp_tpivot

    --Eliminando tabla temporal
    drop table #tmp_tpivot;

END
```

Comment: Hola, en mi caso si yo elijo una fecha corta solo me trae 2 meses, osea solo 2 columnas, por lo que si hago lo que me dices entonces ya no quedaria dinamico, quedaria estatico, como pueod hacer para hacerlo Dinamico?

Comment: @Beterson he editado la respuesta, agregando un script que ilustra como se modificaría la tabla temporal para agregar dinámicamente las columnas requeridas para almacenar los datos del pivote y la inserción de los mismos.